# Insert to more than one table with PHP:PDO on MSSQL

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I'm trying to write a php function which is going to put values to two diferent tables, but it dsn't work. How should I do?

```
public function AddKursplanering($kursBudgetId, $momentId, $momTypID, $pId, $rollId, $tid, $utfall)
{
    if($stmt = $this->m_database->GetPrepareStatement(" INSERT INTO Kursmoment(KBID, MomentID, MomTypID) 
                                                                VALUES(:kursBudgetId, :momentId, :momTypID)
                                                        INSERT INTO Uppgift (KMID, PID, RollID, Tid, Utfall) 
                                                                VALUES (@@IDENTITY, :pId, :rollId, :tid, :utfall)"))
    {
        $stmt->bindValue(':kursBudgetId', $kursBudgetId,PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindValue(':momentId', $momentId,PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindValue(':momTypID', $momTypID,PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindValue(':pId', $pId,PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindValue(':rollId', $rollId,PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindValue(':tid', $tid,PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindValue(':utfall', $utfall,PDO::PARAM_INT);
        if($stmt->execute())
        {
            $stmt->CloseCursor();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say "it doesn't work"?  Do you get an error?  Does MSSQL natively support this syntax?

Comment: be more specific. add error output or highlight what is not working.

Answer (score 0):

- If you are getting an error, post the error text
- If it is not an error, but it is not working for some reason, state clearly what part doesn't work

Now, that should actually work, but use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` instead of `@@IDENTITY`, which may return you an unrelated number if there are triggers involved.

Also, consider encapsulating such logic in a stored procedure with the parameters, so you can call a single proc that does both inserts (essentially the same code)

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the error message from the query above it look like you need to have a semi-colon between the statements.  Without it, it will be interpreted as one query instead of two.

```
if($stmt = $this->m_database->GetPrepareStatement("
  INSERT INTO Kursmoment(KBID, MomentID, MomTypID) 
    VALUES(:kursBudgetId, :momentId, :momTypID);
  INSERT INTO Uppgift (KMID, PID, RollID, Tid, Utfall)
    VALUES (@@IDENTITY, :pId, :rollId, :tid, :utfall)"))
```